# Placeholder and regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to find all the placeholders in a string with this format:

```
hbdfhasbf {{ f1 }} dsnfjnfsdn {{ e4 }}
```

I need to extract all the string that are between `{{` and `}}` excluded the white spaces.

I have tried

```
var matches = from Match match in Regex.Matches(spellDto.Tooltip, @"\{{ ^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}$ }}")
                              select match.Groups[1].Value;
```

but it don't work.

Comment: If you remove those anchors (`^`, `$`) who knows it might work.

Answer (score 2):

The following would also work for you:

```
({{.*?}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
\{\{\s*([A-Za-z][0-9])\s*\}\}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<={{)[^}]+(?=}})
```

Gets whatevers between {{ and }}